# System.StackOverflowException when trying to call Singleton method

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton

I'm working on a small password generator in c# wpf. I've got a Log class which has methods to log messages into files. It was working fine until i added logs when radio checked.
My Log class:

```
public sealed class Log : MainWindow
    {
        private static Log instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();
        public string Date;

        public bool isStarted;

        Log()
        {
            isStarted = false;
        }

        public static Log Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Log();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }

        public void ActivityLog(string message, bool start)
        {
            if(isStarted)
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("activity.log", true, Encoding.ASCII);
                if (start)
                    sw.WriteAsync($"\n[{Date}] {message}\n");
                else
                    sw.WriteAsync($"[{Date}] {message}\n");

                sw.Close();
            }     
        }

        public void PasswordLog(string message)
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("passwords.log", true, Encoding.ASCII);
            sw.WriteAsync($"[{Date}] {message}\n");
            sw.Close();
        }

    }
```

And here is the code that causes the exception(if i comment this code it works fine)

```
private void radioChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)sender;
            switch (radio.Name)
            {
                case "startUpper":
                    Log.Instance.ActivityLog("Start with set to uppercase character", false);
                    break;
                case "startLower":
                    Log.Instance.ActivityLog("Start with set to lowercase character", false);
                    break;
                case "startNumber":
                    Log.Instance.ActivityLog("Start with set to number", false);
                    break;
                case "startSpecial":
                    Log.Instance.ActivityLog("Start with set to special character", false);
                    break;
                case "startDefault":
                    Log.Instance.ActivityLog("Start with set to default", false);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And there's the xaml of these radio buttons

```
<Grid Margin="0,75,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="190" Width="180">
            <Label x:Name="startWithLabel" Content="Start with:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="25" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}" Width="170" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
            <RadioButton Checked="radioChecked" x:Name="startUpper" Content="Uppercase letter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}"/>
            <RadioButton Checked="radioChecked" x:Name="startLower" Content="Lowercase letter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}"/>
            <RadioButton Checked="radioChecked" x:Name="startNumber" Content="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}"/>
            <RadioButton Checked="radioChecked" x:Name="startSpecial" Content="Special character" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}"/>
            <RadioButton Checked="radioChecked" x:Name="startDefault" Content="Default" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource COPRGT}"/>
        </Grid>
```

When im trying to compile it throws exception at window initialization `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: There is probably some infinite recursion going on. Look at the stack trace (add it to your question if you need help spotting the recursion).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, if would be very useful if you could create a [mcve] which contains *only* the code necessary to reproduce the issue: removing any line should either cause the issue to go away, or your code to not compile

Comment: Since `isStarted` is never set to `true` the calls to `ActivityLog` shouldn't do anything at all.

Comment: Also you have an async call that isn't awaited followed by closing the `StreamWriter` it's call on, which is going to an issue when your code gets to that point.

Comment: Instead of writing your own logging code I suggest using an existing logging library instead.

Comment: I've got a checkbox to set that to true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack overflow is usually caused by infinite recursion. (method A calls method B, which calls method A, etc.)

This is just a wild guess without seeing the stack trace, but my guess is this:

```
public sealed class Log : MainWindow
```

Why does it inherit from `MainWindow`? That means that all the code in `MainWindow` is running when a new `Log` is created. If that `radioChecked` is in `MainWindow`, then that's likely what's causing the recursion.

Comment: I forgot to remove this inheritance(it was for the sake of debug). It worked, thanks a lot